# Grab output of a command lines in linux bash unusual result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, imagemagick, compare

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(compare -subimage-search -metric mae large_image.png item.png result.png)
echo "Output is: $output"
```

It displays like something like this:

```
7216.53 (0.110117) @ 6,4
Output is:
```

But I am expecting something like this

```
Output is: 7216.53 (0.110117) @ 6,4
```

It seems to me that compare(imagemagick) is using other print line command other than 'print' or 'echo'

I have no problem with other command line such as:

```
output=$(date)
echo "output is: $output"
```

This will yield to:

```
output is: Fri Nov 22 01:02:07 PHT 2013
```

Comment: It sounds like your compare command is not writing to STOUT.  If you run `compare ... > /dev/null` do you see any output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `compare` is writing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`

Try this command:

```
output=$(compare -subimage-search -metric mae large_image.png item.png result.png 2>&1)
echo "Output is: $output"
```

Comment: wow, thanks, perfect. I keeping seeing 2>&1 examples but never had any idea what was it all about until now. tnx